# How can I make my API request working via Postman?

Tags: python, api, http-post, postman

I am working with Postman for the first time and GET request to my simple API is working fine, but when I try POST request it gives me an error and I have no idea where is the problem. Can you please advise?

API function:

```
@app.route('/customer', methods=['POST'])
def create_customer():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    new_customer = {
        "email": request_data['email'],
        "username": request_data['username'],
        "name": request_data['name'],
        "newsletter_status": request_data['newsletter_status'],
        "trips": []
    }
    for customer in customers:
        if customer['username'] == new_customer['username']:
            return jsonify({'error': 'username already exist'})
    customers.append(new_customer)
    return jsonify(new_customer)
```

Screenshots from postman
[This I put in the body + error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTqYg.png)

[Headers set up - Content-Type application/json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDeeh.png)

Comment: Can you check in the Postman console what exactly is being sent?

Answer (score 0):

I think your new customer variables should not be in string format, I don't know why they are and also try my option for getting the request body:

```
import json

def create_customer():
    request_data = json.loads(request.body)
    new_customer = {
        email = request_data['email'],
        username = request_data['username'],
        name = request_data['name'],
        newsletter_status = request_data['newsletter_status'],
        trips: []
    }
    for customer in customers:
        if customer['username'] == new_customer['username']:
            return jsonify({'error': 'username already exist'})
    customers.append(new_customer)
    return jsonify(new_customer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yur code works fine , i just tested with postman:

```
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/customer', methods=['POST'])
def create_customer():
    customers=[]
    customers.append(request.get_json())
    request_data = request.get_json()
    new_customer = {
        "email": request_data['email'],
        "username": request_data['username']+"HHH",
        "name": request_data['name'],
        "newsletter_status": request_data['newsletter_status'],
        "trips": []
    }
    print(new_customer['username'])
    print(customers[0]['username'])
    for customer in customers:
        if customer['username'] == new_customer['username']:
            return jsonify({'error': 'username already exist'})
    customers.append(new_customer)
    return jsonify(new_customer)
```

Can you check what is exactly send in postman ?

you can do it by clicking console ( can get from left botom corner or by pressing ctrl+alt+c ) >request > requestbody

[image]

Comment: Thanks PDHide 
Seems then my code is okay. Still I dont know where is the problem. When I check the console and "request body" I see the details of new customers are sent correctly. However, I still get the error message "400 Bad request"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)</p>↵

Any idea where could be the problem? maybe in some Postman setup?

Comment: @petr where is this customers array coming from ? I haven't seen the global keyword used

Comment: Can you add the application console log ?